# Simulation stuck while producing the agents in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have 100 cubic meter tank and I have 133,333 bottles to fill. When tank get fill I am using

```
source.injact(133,333)
```

My first issue was a lack of memory, which I resolved, and now agents are being produced; however, once the source began producing, the simulation stuck and run very slow. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 100,000 agents and if all of them are using the fluid library, there's a chance that things will be very slow.

That's all i can say with the information provided.

I wouldn't use the fluid library inside a bottle agent... I would model that differently (if you are doing that, which i don't know if you are)

It can also be that your computer is slow

Comment: What that means "I wouldn't use the fluid library inside a bottle agent".

Comment: i means that if you have 100 thousand agents, it's a bad idea to have fluid library objects inside it since the fluid library is slow

Comment: Because the fluid computations are done for each agent individually. If you have 100k agents, you have to be very careful what you let them do